# Exercise on local and global symmetry for a given Lagrangian density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, quantum-electrodynamics

> **The following Lagrangian density describes a charged scalar field. Determine the global U(1) symmetry. Make this global symmetry local and give the Lagrangian density. The Lagrangian density is given by**: $$L = \partial_\mu \psi \partial^\mu \psi^* - \frac{1}{2}m^2|\psi|^2 - \frac{1}{4}\lambda|\psi|^2.$$

My first idea was to perform the following transformation (because it is mentioned we are dealing with U(1) invariance):
$$\psi \rightarrow e^{i\theta}\psi$$ $$\psi^* \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}\psi^*$$
$$\partial_\mu \psi \rightarrow D_\mu \psi = (\partial_\mu + iqA_\mu)\psi$$ and $$\partial_\mu \psi^* \rightarrow D_\mu \psi^* = (\partial_\mu - iqA_\mu)\psi^*$$
However I think this is what you have to do to obtain a local symmetry out of the global one. I have no idea how to find the global one.

In short my questions are:

1. How do you find the global U(1) symmetry for a given Lagrangian density?
2. Is the way to determine the local symmetry out of the global U(1) symmetry achieved by transforming in the following way: $\psi \rightarrow e^{i\theta}\psi$, $\psi^* \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}\psi^*$,
   $\partial_\mu \psi \rightarrow D_\mu \psi = (\partial_\mu + iqA_\mu)\psi$ and $\partial_\mu \psi^* \rightarrow D_\mu \psi^* = (\partial_\mu - iqA_\mu)\psi^*$?

Thanks in advance!