# Exercise on gauge invariance and global and local symmetry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance

> **The following Lagrangian density describes a charged scalar field. Determine the global U(1) symmetry. Make this global symmetry local, give the Lagrangian density and show that this is Gauge invariant. The Lagrangian density is given by**: $$L = \partial_\mu \psi \partial^\mu \psi^* - \frac{1}{2}m^2|\psi|^2 - \frac{1}{4}\lambda|\psi|^2.$$

My first idea was to perform the following transformation (because it is mentioned we are dealing with U(1) invariance):
$$\psi \rightarrow e^{i\theta}\psi$$ $$\psi^* \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}\psi^*$$
$$\partial_\mu \psi \rightarrow D_\mu \psi = (\partial_\mu + iqA_\mu)\psi$$ and $$\partial_\mu \psi^* \rightarrow D_\mu \psi^* = (\partial_\mu - iqA_\mu)\psi^*$$
However I think this is what you have to do to obtain a local symmetry out of the global one. I have no idea how to find the global one.

In short my questions are:

1. How do you find the global U(1) symmetry for a given Lagrangian density?
2. Is the way to determine the local symmetry out of the global U(1) symmetry achieved by transforming in the following way: $\psi \rightarrow e^{i\theta}\psi$, $\psi^* \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}\psi^*$,
   $\partial_\mu \psi \rightarrow D_\mu \psi = (\partial_\mu + iqA_\mu)\psi$ and $\partial_\mu \psi^* \rightarrow D_\mu \psi^* = (\partial_\mu - iqA_\mu)\psi^*$?
3. Is every Lagrangian density where you performed the transformation given in 2. Gauge invariant? If not, how can you check whether the Lagrangian density is Gauge invariant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574177/2451

Comment: Hi Feynmannah. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that! I tried to edit my previous post but I had some problems, so that's why I created a new post that was more focused on one topic (while the previous one contained a lot of different questions).